# Horizontal scrollbar appears in dev tools, but not in the website

Tags: css, developer-tools

I have run [my website](http://www.itumeli.co.il) through the device bar on the dev tools and there is a horizontal scroll there (together with a locally hosted WP site). I tried browsing it in my device but there is no actual horizontal scroll - it only appears on dev tools.

What can possibly cause a horizontal scroll in dev tools but not in the website itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "horizontal scroll in dev tools"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `min-width: 320px;` from `.hero-container` it causes problems on small screen devices which causes extra padding on the side. Remove `width: 80%` and set it to `width: auto` instead.

[image: Safari Responsive Mode]

Comment: @Ivan he'll need to remove the width using a media query as well. It's the main problem.

Comment: Yes, this will work but you will have to set the width: auto;

Comment: @Droid Updated :) Thanks.

Comment: @Win No prob :)

Comment: @Win fixed! However, now there is nothing to keep the paragraph length low. If the width is "auto", how should I keep a low paragraph (div) length?